# Convert IPv4 string to a BIGINT representation in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I convert a IPv4 ip adress from string to a long representation using SPARK SQL (hiveish)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using multiplication :

```
sqlContext.sql("""SELECT 
       (cast(split(l.klientip,'\\.')[0] as bigint) * 16777216) 
     + (cast(split(l.klientip,'\\.')[1] as bigint) * 65536 ) 
     + (cast(split(l.klientip,'\\.')[2] as bigint) * 256) 
     + (cast(split(l.klientip,'\\.')[3] as bigint) ) ip_add_int 
     from loggik l
     """).show()
```

Or with bitshifting (same as multiplication)

```
sqlContext.sql("""SELECT
      (shiftLeft(cast(split(l.klientip,'\\.')[0] as bigint),24) 
        +shiftLeft(cast(split(l.klientip,'\\.')[1] as bigint),16)
        +shiftLeft(cast(split(l.klientip,'\\.')[2] as bigint),8)
        +cast(split(l.klientip,'\\.')[3] as bigint)) ip_shift_int 
     from loggik l
     """).show()
```